# Slow SD Writing for fuel injection and tps motorcycle

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, spi

```
#include <PCD8544.h>

#include <BlockDriver.h>
#include <FreeStack.h>
#include <MinimumSerial.h>
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <SdFatConfig.h>
#include <SysCall.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <elapsedMillis.h>

static PCD8544 lcd;
float Sensor_fuelinj = A5;
float Sensor_tps = A4;
float fuel_injector_value = 0;
float tps_yellow_value = 0;
float a = 0;
float b = 0;

SdFat SD;
SdFile myFile;
int pinCS = 10;
int i = 0;
char filename[] = "Text00.txt";

elapsedMillis timeElapsed;  
unsigned int interval = 10000;


void fileNaming()
{
  for (i = 0; i < 99; i++)
  {
    filename[4] = i / 10 + '0';
    filename[5] = i % 10 + '0';
    if (! SD.exists(filename))
    {
      myFile.open(filename,  O_CREAT | O_WRITE);
      break;
    }
 }
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(Sensor_fuelinj, INPUT);
  pinMode(Sensor_tps, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinCS, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  lcd.begin(84, 48);
  lcd.setContrast(60);

  if (SD.begin(pinCS, SPI_FULL_SPEED))
  {
    Serial.println("Setup is ready.");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
    lcd.print("Ready!");
    delay (1000);
    lcd.clear();
  } else
  {
    Serial.println("Setup is not ready.");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
    lcd.print("Not Ready!");
    delay (2000);
    setup();
  }
  fileNaming();
}


void loop()
{

  a = analogRead(Sensor_fuelinj);
  b = analogRead(Sensor_tps);

  fuel_injector_value = a * 5 / 1024 * 2;
  tps_yellow_value = b * 5 / 1024 * 1220 / 220;

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(filename);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("Fuel Injector:");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print(fuel_injector_value);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 4);
  lcd.print("TPS          :");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 5);
  lcd.print(tps_yellow_value);


  if (timeElapsed < interval)
  {
    myFile.print(millis());
    myFile.print(",");
    myFile.print(fuel_injector_value);
    myFile.print(",");
    myFile.print(tps_yellow_value);
    myFile.println("");

    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(fuel_injector_value);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(tps_yellow_value);
    Serial.println("");

  }
  else
  {
    myFile.close();
    lcd.setCursor(65, 0);
    lcd.print("OK!");
    fileNaming();
    delay(1000);
    lcd.setCursor(65, 0);
    lcd.print("3..");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.setCursor(65, 0);
    lcd.print("2..");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.setCursor(65, 0);
    lcd.print("1..");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.setCursor(65, 0);
    lcd.print("   ");
    timeElapsed = 0;
   } 

}
```

I constructed the code above to log the data fuel injections and TPS value along with milliseconds to determine the timing for skipping fuel injections.

The hypothesis is the fuel will be injected every rpm: if my motorcycle cruising at `3000rpm`, it means my SD must be able to log at least 50 samples per second or 50HZ. However, even though I set my SPI to full speed, I am only able to log at the highest speed of 25 samples per second...

How should I refine my code... I am a mechanical engineering student.

Comment: **1.** Do you use file buffering? Typically writing many values at once is faster than writing one at the time. **2.** Do you really need to transmit to serial port while logging? **3.** Do you really need to update lcd on each iteration? **4.** Do you really need to write file in text mode, instead of binary mode? I'm no expert on arduino speed, but on some low end systems, even converting integers to string can be too slow. **5. Have you done benchmark to determine which code section slows you down the most?**